# Error trying to install a WP8.1 App in Windows Phone Mobile

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

Trying to install a WP8.1 App in a new Windows Phone Mobile 10 we are getting this error (We are using the "*Windows Phone Application Deployment (8.1)*" App):

> Error - The provided package is already installed, and reinstallation
>   of the package was blocked. Check the AppXDeployment-Server event log
>   for details.

First, the app is not installed. We have verified twice.
Second, what is the AppXDeployment-Server and where I can find the log?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as simple as update the Windows Phone OS to the latest version. 
After that we can install WP8.1 Apps in Windows Phone Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

> First, the app is not installed. We have verified twice.

This error usually occurs when installing a package which is not bitwise identical to the package that is already installed. Therefore, if a package is rebuilt or resigned, it’s no longer bitwise identical to the **previously** installed package.

To fix it, you can increase your app’s version number, then rebuild and resign the package or remove the old package for every user on the system before installing the new one.

Besides, you mean the app is not installed before? That way you should use Windows Phone Application Deployment to install the package in default (C:) but not on the device SD card. If you want to install it on SD card, you should use Visual Studio to deploy your app.

> Second, what is the AppXDeployment-Server and where I can find the log?

The AppXDeployment-Server provide more info to help you diagnose the cause of the error code.

You can follow steps below to access the event log:

•   Run **eventvwr.msc**.

•   Go to **Event Viewer** (Local) > **Applications and Services Logs** > **Microsoft** > **Windows**.

•   The first log to check is **AppxPackagingOM** > **Microsoft-Windows-AppxPackaging/Operational**.

•   Deployment-related errors are recorded in **AppXDeployment-Server** > **Microsoft-Windows-AppXDeploymentServer/Operational**.

Also, another option is to use PowerShell, try following command:

**Get-Appxlog|Out-GridView**

For more details, you might refer [Troubleshooting packaging, deployment, and query of Windows Store apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh973484(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks @Mattew.. The solution was as simple as update the Windows Phone OS to the latest version. Thanks!